# How is it proved (intuitively) that the more independent vectors the "larger" the vector subspace will be

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Say there is just one vector:
$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 2 \\ 3\end{bmatrix}$$

That vector,can "make up"/form just a line.

Now,if one more (independent) vector is appended then:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 
                  2 & 9 \\
                  3 & 10 \end{bmatrix}$$

These two vectors,can form a plane.

And at last,if one more vector is added:

$$\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
                  2 & 9 & 0 \\
                  3 & 10 & 1 \end{bmatrix}$$
then,

$$ \mathbb{R^3}$$

is produced

Why is that?A fairly simpler question would be: why the sum of two vectors laying on the same plane result in a vector also in that plane?

Thanks!

Comment: For your last question, intuitively, take a flat piece of paper, draw a line segment on it, then a second line segment which begins at the end of the first. Isn't is intuitively clear that the line segment, from the start of the first segment, to the end of the second, also lies in the same flat piece of paper?

Answer (score 0):

Because a plane (passing through the origin) is a vector subspace and, by definition, the sum of two elements of a subspace also belongs to that subspace.